# Where did my friend go?

Tags: cipher, enigmatic-puzzle, steganography

My vacation is off to a great start! I have traveled far and wide, but never have I seen anything like this! Perhaps you already know where I am, but if not, here's a photo:

[image: Photo]

Your friend,

Jessica...

Comment: Could we have a transcription of the piece of paper (using arbitrary letters for each character)?

Comment: @Deusovi, I may post a transcript, but it will take away a couple of clues in the photo itself.

Answer (score 3):

#### Partial Answer

Reading the image

> as RGB values in ASCII gives `i.stack.imgur.com/0JB7s.jpg`, leading to this image:
>
>  [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0JB7s.jpg]
>
>  It's almost certainly a substitution cipher, but I'm not really willing to transcribe it at the moment.

Answer (score 3):

A possible transcription of the letter Deusovi found is:

> ```
>    VLCTADBY NXTKX TQWX NBQKDX
>    LQUHLK SLQNK VXIH QS KYLQTHN
>    KX GHNK
>    D UDM ZQR VOM DT BLXBFDTV IZ BDJIHL
> ```

This is ...

> ... a substitution cipher, but with an additional feature: Double letters arerepresented by a special syntax. The third letter (C above) is the top view of an Phoenician house with a semicircle to the left. This is the double letter H, the Phoenician house without circle.
>
>  Likewise, the penultimate letter in the third row from the bottom (O) is the double letter Q, a sideways fancy stacked burger. So semi-circular shapes attached to the left of a letter mean a double letter.

The text decodes to:

> Greenwich
>    Santa
>    Nova Scotia
>    Robert Frost
>    Game of Thrones
>    Tallest
>    I bid you good in cracking my cipher
>
>  There's a typo in the last word: The pitched tent (I) should be the upside-down candelabra (Y). The one-of-a-kind letter in "tallest" (G) also has a semicircle, so it could be a double letter. Of the ones not used, L makes the most sense.

But:

> That's not a destination yet. (Greenwich and Nova Scotia are, but I think they are just intermediate answers.) The question has a steganography tag and I guess it applies to the decoded message.

Comment: I was confused what you meant about the typo at first, but now I think you just speak a non-American dialect of English - "cipher" is the standard spelling in the US, but I've just learned that "cypher" is common elsewhere.

Comment: It's not about cipher/cypher, but about cipher/cipmer. The fourth letter should be an H, which occurs twice (in Greenwich and Thrones) and is an upside down three-armed candelabra. The actual letter is what looks like the side view of a house with a vertical stroke, which, according to my decoding, should be an M, as in Game and My.

Comment: Well then I'm very confused why you typed "I" and "Y" in parentheses, which makes it seem like you're saying the I should be a Y.

Comment: @Personman: The letters in parentheses refer to my transcription. I've mapped the symbols to Latin letters so that I can feed them to a [cryptogram solver](http://quipqiup.com/). I have tried to be mnemonic, so I've chosen letters that look a bit like the symbols. The first symbol, the tanga on the buttocks, is V, the XD ligature is X and so on. I chose Y for the candelabra and I for the house/tent thing. (I've said "C above" to mean "in the transcription above" in the first parenthetical annotation, which is probably a bit vague.)